# $f(x)=$ area under the curve of $f(x)$ in range $<0,x)$. $f(0)$ has a set value.

Tags: integration, functions

The title might be confusing. I tried to simplify and generalize my problem. I have a function $$f(x) = \frac{a-(\text{area under curve before $x$})}{\pi*(b-x)^2}$$
While the function would begin in $f(0)$ so $(\text{area under curve before $x$})$ would equal $0$ there.

I thought of using sums for the calculation of area before $x$. But isn't there an integral that could do this? My question is how to express the area under the curve before $x$. Thanks.

(I don't know how to google this because I can't name the phenomena correctly]

Comment: Would not $\int_0^x f(t) \, \mathrm dt$ suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area under the curve is either $\displaystyle \int_0^x f(t)\mathop{dt}$ or $\displaystyle \int_0^x |f(t)|\mathop{dt}$ whether you want an algebric (signed) area or the intuitive (geometric) definition.

Of course if $f(t)\ge 0$ the definition is the same.

Note also that you have $\displaystyle \bigg(\int_0^x f(t)\mathop{dt}\bigg)'=f(x)$

Let assume $f$ does not annulates, then our expression becomes

$f(x)=\dfrac{a-\int_0^x f(t)\mathop{dt}}{\pi(b-x)^2}$ and can be derivated to obtain an ODE verified by $f$.

$-f(x)=f'(x)\pi(b-x)^2-f(x)2\pi(b-x)\iff \dfrac {f'}{f}=\dfrac{1+2\pi(b-x)}{\pi(b-x)^2}$

Which solves to $\large f(x)=C\cdot\dfrac{e^{\frac 1{\pi(b-x)}}}{(b-x)^2}$.